# assigning QueryString value as a hidden field value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Just like the inquire on the best way of doing this. I am retrieving a querystring value in an aspx page and this value I want to assign as the value of the hidden input field.

```
<%int productId = 0;
  if (Request.QueryString["productId"] != "" && Request.QueryString["productId"] != null)
  {
      productId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["productId"]);

  } %>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenProdIdEditProduct" value=<% productId %> />
```

As it is at the moment I get a compilation error.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the '=' <%= productId %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to have this logic directly in your ASP.NET aspx page.

Assign it server side, for example in the `Page_Load` event.

```
int productId = 0;
if (Request.QueryString["productId"] != "" && Request.QueryString["productId"] != null)
{
  productId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["productId"]);
}

hiddenProdidEditProduct.Text = productId;
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Not too fond of runat='server' but this is probably the best option.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it using, Why do you need to convert it `int`.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenProdIdEditProduct" value='<% Request.QueryString["productId"] %>' />
```

You might be getting as `value` which is not of `int` type.

Or use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

```
<%
   int productId = 0;
   Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["productId"], out productId);
%>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenProdIdEditProduct" value='<% productId %>' />
```